# Mock the object initialization part in the Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Say I have a below method to upload files into Azure Blob.

```
public async Task BlobFileUpload(string content)
{            
    BlobClient blob = new BlobClient(connectionstring, containername, blobName);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
    {
        await blob.UploadAsync(ms, true);
    }
}
```

Now how to write a Unit Test case for this method (XUnit, Moq).

I can mock the services and their methods like uploadAsync etc. But here BlobClient is declared and initialized in the Method itself.

So when I call this method from test class, a new object of BlobClient is getting created with original configuration.

Please help me in mocking that BlobClient object creation.

Comment: It's not possible with constrained isolating frameworks such as Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy. This can be done using unconstrained tools such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, AutoFake, Unmockable, Harmony, MethodRedirect, Pose, Shimmy.

Comment: Testing such method with mock will provide little feedback or confidence, because you are just testing that you wrote specific methods without errors. Instead spin up Azurite with blob storage emulator and write the test which will test that file is uploaded to the blob storage.